# Rails Helper Method in Controller to apply to all pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an instagram feed in my footer. When I insert the method in my controller that applies to my views it only shows on the first page (see below)

```
    class CreativesController < ApplicationController
  layout "creative"



  def index
    **@instagram = Instagram.user_recent_media(:count => 1)**
    @campaigns = storage.list_for(params[:page], params[:tag])
    @campaigned = Campaign.order("created_at DESC").limit(6)
    @recent = Campaign.order("created_at DESC").limit(3)

    end

    # GET /posts/1
    # GET /posts/1.json
  def show

    @campaign = storage.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @gallery = storage.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end

  def gallery
   @galleries = storage.list_for(params[:page], params[:tag])
    @galleried = Gallery.order("created_at DESC")
    @current = Gallery.order("created_at DESC")

  end


  private

  def storage
    Campaign.published
    Gallery.published

  end







end
```

I get the following:

[image: first photo]

Now when I navigate to a different page I am getting the following error:

[image: second photo]

What I want to do and am having a problem figuring out is applying the instagram method to the application controller to apply it to all pages so it loads for all pages in the footer without giving me the error.

Here is what my application.controller looks like now:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  layout 'author'
 before_action :load_posts
 def instagram
    @instagram = Instagram.user_recent_media(:count => 1)
 end

private

  def load_posts
    @posts = Post.order("created_at DESC").limit(3)
  end

end
```

I am still getting the same error.

This is what my footer code looks like:

```
<!-- Latest -->
                        <div class="col-md-3 md-margin-bottom-40">
                            <div class="posts">
                                <div class="headline"><h2>Latest Instagram Post</h2></div>
                            <% @instagram.each do |instagram| %>

              <%= image_tag instagram.images.standard_resolution.url, class: "img-responsive" %>

                <%= instagram.caption.text %>


            <%end%>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- End Latest -->
```

This is what my routes look like:

```
 get 'contacts/index'

  get 'document/download'
  get 'confirmation/confirmation'
  get 'document/download'
  get 'show' => 'maps#show_image'

  root 'creatives#index'
  get '/about' => 'creatives#about'
  get '/news' => 'creatives#news'
  get '/careers' => 'creatives#careers'
  get '/contacts' => 'creatives#contacts'
  get '/gallery' => 'creatives#gallery'
  get '/geopath' => 'creatives#geopath'
  get '/steps' => 'creatives#steps'
  get '/browse' => 'maps#show'
  get '/search' => 'maps#index'
  get '/design' => 'creatives#design'
  post "favorite", to: "maps#favorite"
  post "unfavorite", to: "maps#unfavorite"
```

Update 2

I changed my creatives controller and added the following and it works except for a few other pages that are using different controllers. Now it works this way but I am trying to see if there is a simpler method to apply it across all pages without having to repeat the code over and over. This is where I think I need to add something to the application method but I cannot figure it out.

```
class CreativesController < ApplicationController
  layout "creative"


def about
@instagram = Instagram.user_recent_media(:count => 1)
end

def careers
@instagram = Instagram.user_recent_media(:count => 1)
end

def contacts
@instagram = Instagram.user_recent_media(:count => 1)
end

def design
@instagram = Instagram.user_recent_media(:count => 1)
end

def geopath
@instagram = Instagram.user_recent_media(:count => 1)
end

def news
@instagram = Instagram.user_recent_media(:count => 1)
end

def steps
@instagram = Instagram.user_recent_media(:count => 1)
end

  def index
    @instagram = Instagram.user_recent_media(:count => 1)
    @campaigns = storage.list_for(params[:page], params[:tag])
    @campaigned = Campaign.order("created_at DESC").limit(6)
    @recent = Campaign.order("created_at DESC").limit(3)

    end

    # GET /posts/1
    # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
@instagram = Instagram.user_recent_media(:count => 1)
    @campaign = storage.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @gallery = storage.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end

  def gallery
    @instagram = Instagram.user_recent_media(:count => 1)
   @galleries = storage.list_for(params[:page], params[:tag])
    @galleried = Gallery.order("created_at DESC")
    @current = Gallery.order("created_at DESC")

  end


  private

  def storage
    Campaign.published
    Gallery.published

  end







end
```

I was given the correct answer I just added the code I was given to my application controller to apply it across all of the views.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  layout 'author'
 before_action :load_posts
  before_action :set_instagram


private
 def set_instagram
    @instagram = Instagram.user_recent_media(count: 1)
  end
  def load_posts
    @posts = Post.order("created_at DESC").limit(3)
  end

end
```

Comment: Is there an about action? Clearly you must pass @instagram to your view from the controller.

Comment: @SebastianPalma I am able to pass it for one page. I need to apply it across all of the pages and I am unsure of how to do so.

Comment: You're not receiving and/or sending that variable to the action that responds to the /about route, that's why I'm asking

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are talking about forgive me I am still a junior but see my update I added my routes.

Comment: `get '/about' => 'creatives#about'` is there an about action in your CreativesController, I can't see it.

Comment: No there is not.

Comment: So, I don't know how you render that view. Also, post code, no images.

Comment: I added a second update and I only have two images to show results the rest is code so not sure what you are talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that repetitive case you can use a before_action callback.

```
class CreativesController < ApplicationController
  layout 'creative'
  before_action :set_instagram

  ...

  private

  def set_instagram
    @instagram = Instagram.user_recent_media(count: 1)
  end
end
```

You can use the `only` or `except` options with an array of symbols, where the symbols are the name of each action, depending on the actions you want to set that instance variable before. As you want to set it before each action, then you omit any option.

Comment: Thank you this actually helped. Instead of adding it to my creatives controller I added it to application controller and it worked across all pages.